# get keyname for constraint error in PHP/MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, constraints, mysql-error-1062

If I try to do an insert that fails because of a key constraint error, is there a way I can get the name of the key without doing string parsing of the error text?

I already know the error code is 1062; I want to find out *which* key constraint failed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"without doing string parsing of the error text?" - No, as far as I know doing something like

```
preg_match("/for key '(.+)'$", $msg, $matches)
```

is your best chance.